# Pegar variável de uma função para outra função dentro da mesma classe?

Tags: php

Preciso capturar a variável de uma função para outra função dentro da mesma classe. Abaixo segue escopo de exemplo.

```
public function upPicture()
{
   $variavel = "Hello World!";            
}
public function cadastraPic() 
{
  print_r($variavel); //de dentro da função upPicture
}
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando somente funções você só consegue isso se retornar o valor desejado.

```php
function upPicture(){
    $variavel = "Hello World!";
    return $variavel;
  }

function cadastraPic() {
   $variavel = upPicture();
   print_r($variavel); //de dentro da função upPicture
}
```

Programando de forma orientada a objetos você pode setar uma propriedade na sua classe e o método `upPicture()` seta o valor dessa propriedade para o método `cadastraPic()` poder acessá-lo normalmente. Veja:

```php
class MinhaClasse {
    protected $variavel;

    public function upPicture(){
        $this->variavel = "Hello World!";
      }

    public function cadastraPic() {
       print_r($this->variavel); //de dentro da função upPicture
    }
}

$classe = new MinhaClasse();
$classe->upPicture();
$classe->cadastraPic();
```

Veja este [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pczd-1s6a) (Na página clique em "Run-F9" para executá-lo)